# Click on text to engage dropdown, not div. - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown that I build, it works perfectly. My problem is that I can click on the entire div and it will engage the dropdown. I only want to click on the text to engage the dropdown. Here is a screenshot that will make it more clear.

### Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see. If I were to click anywhere on that div it would engage the dropdown. I only want to click on the text aka the `new project` text. Any help would be great!

Here is my CSS

```
.topbar-team {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  width: 45%;

  &__name {
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: $base-link-color;

    &__text {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 25px;
      left: 40px;
      width: 225px;
    }
  }
}
```

## HTML:

```
  <div class="topbar-team">
    <%= link_to "#projects-dropdown", class: "topbar-team__name", data: { behavior: "dropdown:projects" } do %>
      <div class="project-background">
        <span class="icon icon-project"></span>
      </div>
      <% if current_user.accounts.any? %>
        <span class="topbar-team__name topbar-team__name__text"><%= current_account.name %></span>
      <% else %>
        <span class="topbar-team__name topbar-team__name__text">No Projects</span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Provide the full code HTML + CSS

Comment: That's not CSS, that's SCSS/LESS/SASS. And without HTML, what good is the CSS? As for the clickable on the div, set either a span around the text that you make clickable, or make the div not be 100% wide, so that it wraps the content, either with `float` or `display: inline`

Comment: Updated @SauravRastogi Thank you

Comment: The the html is there @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: How is this dropdown invoked?

Comment: With JS @Roberrrt I'll update the question to add that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap text in `<span>` and apply click event to it instead of `<div>`. Also you can make div same width as text with `float`/`display: inline-block`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div span, .div2').click(function() {
    console.log('Click Event ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
  });
});
```

```css
span,
div {
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 200, .5);
  padding: 3px;
}
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>TEXT TO CLICK</span>
</div>
<div class="div2">TEXT TO CLICK</div>
```